# onenote-2010 handwriting quality: jaggedy text

Tags: microsoft-onenote-2010, handwriting

I'm using OneNote 2010 and this week I'm using an old backup machine, 2GHz 2GB ram Win XP pro machine.

So its a downgrade from my usual Win 7 3 GHz 8G ram machine, but here's the problem.

In onenote 2010 on the Win 7 machine, handwriting is beautiful.  It captures it almost exactly as you wrote it.  Using a Wacom tablet.

On this XP laptop, the handwriting *goes down* very well (showing there's no problem w/ the Wacom driver), but a couple of seconds later, the "approximation" it saves out to disk is **very poor** (very jaggedy) with visibly like 10-15 points per letter (which makes it visibly harder to read).

I don't want to have to throw my work away until I can get my old machine back, is there a way to fix this problem?
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to get a better machine.  It appears the resolution of saved points is determined by CPU speed, available memory, or a combination of both.

Answer (score 0):

Have you optimized the machine? Remove all unnecessary running background applications and services. The system needs as many resources as possible to perform this task, and giving it as much as possible should not only improve the quality of the saved text, but the generally snappiness of the system.

Comment: Yeah, I did.  It seems its a onenote setting.. the machine is _performing_ smoothly, apparently.